# How use notification icon from React Native app to some RNBridge?

Tags: android, react-native, responsys, react-native-bridge

I created a [bridge to React Native](https://github.com/juntossomosmais/react-native-responsys) to work with Oracle-Responsys SDK.

The bridge is working pretty well, but the only thing that I'm stuck is in how can I set the notifications icons from my react native app to this bridge.

Following the [documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/responsys-develop-mobile/android/sounds-icons/) from Responsys:

```
PushIOManager.getInstance(this).setDefaultSmallIcon(R.drawable.emo_im_surprised);
PushIOManager.getInstance(this).setDefaultLargeIcon(R.drawable.emo_im_happy);
```

Notes: The Integer value must be a resource ID generated by the build system. In the calls above, the icon name represents the Integer value. For example, R.drawable.emo_im_surprised is the Integer value of the icon emo_im_surprised.png that has been placed in the drawable folder.

I got this, but this `R.drawable` references my bridge`s drawable not the app drawable, how can i use the icons from my app inside my bridge?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this creating this function:

```java
private  int getDrawableId(String name) {
        String packageName = getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        return getReactApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", packageName);
}
```

and using it like this:

```java
  Integer notificationIcon = getDrawableId("ic_responsys_alt");
  pushIOManager.setDefaultSmallIcon(notificationIcon);
```

with this code, you just need to add an icon called `ic_responsys_alt` inside app drawable folder.

[that's the bridge we developed](https://github.com/juntossomosmais/react-native-responsys)